# The last cycle in the code doesn't see printf

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I need to convert the entered number into a five-digit system. But the last cycle in the code does not see printf regardless of what you want to output, but in any other part of the code everything works fine. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_NUM 6
#define MAX_ARR 20

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf("\n\n");
    unsigned long long n;
    int numArray[MAX_ARR];
    int count = 0, i, j;
    printf("Введіть довге ціле число: ");
    scanf_s("%llu", &n);
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    if (count > MAX_NUM)
    {
        printf("\nЧисло занадто велике. Введіть число менше або рівне 6: ");
        scanf_s("%llu", &n);
        count = 0;
        while (n != 0)
        {
            n /= 10;
            count++;
        }
        while (count > MAX_NUM)
        {
            printf("\nЧисло занадто велике. Введіть число менше або рівне 6: ");
            scanf_s("%llu", &n);
            count = 0;
            while (n != 0)
            {
                n /= 10;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
    {
        numArray[i] = n % 5;
        n /= 5;
        printf(" %d ", numArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "a five-digit system"?  Can you provide example(s)?

Comment: When the first loop ends, `n == 0`. You need to use a different variable when counting the number of digits.

Comment: It's like binary but quinary

Comment: @NikitaIvankov The term is "base 5"

Comment: @Barmar why? If n = 222222, after first loop it will be 44444

Comment: In the future always provide a [mre] with debugging questions, including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead.

Comment: @NikitaIvankov The condition of the first loop is `while (n != 0)`. So the loop ends when `n == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

After while loops as for example the first while loop

```
while (n != 0)
{
    n /= 10;
    count++;
}
```

`n` is equal to `0`.

So the following for loop

```
for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
```

will be skipped.

You need to use an intermediate variable in loops like this

```
        while (n != 0)
        {
            n /= 10;
            count++;
        }
```

the following way

```
unsigned long long tmp = n;

do
{
    ++count;
} while ( tmp /= 10 );
```

Pay attention to that `0` is a valid number. You should not ignore it.

Also the array `numArray` is redundant because it is not used in the program apart from this assignment

```
numArray[i] = n % 5;
```

You could use it like

```
i = 0;
do
{
    numArray[i++] = n % 5;
} while ( n /= 5 );
```

Then you could output the array in the reverse order like

```
while ( i )
{
    printf( "%d", numArray[--i] );
}
```